# SCL Centos nodejs10 - still "secure/up-to-date"

Tags: software-collections

I need to install nodejs10 on a CentOS 7 box - so I tried using SCL to achieve this goal:

```
#yum install centos-release-scl-rh
#yum install rh-nodejs10
#scl enable rh-nodejs10 bash

#node -v
v10.10.0
```

So this version is not the most recent, but if all necessary patches are applied this should be OK.

Based on [Red Hat Software Collections Product Life Cycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl/) the Support is from Nov 2018 to Apr 2021 so I would expect everything is fine.

So I tried to find out which version / what patches are applied. Because rh-nodejs10 is a meta-rpm (?) I queried the rpm-db for information about the installed packages / dependencies and displayed the infos.

```
# rpm -qiRl rh-nodejs10
Name        : rh-nodejs10
Version     : 3.2
Release     : 2.el7
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sa 04 Mai 2019 12:43:55 CEST
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 0
..
Source RPM  : rh-nodejs10-3.2-2.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Di 30 Okt 2018 14:17:17 CET
Packager    : CBS <cbs@centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
Summary     : rh-nodejs10 Software Collection
Description :
This is the main package for rh-nodejs10 Software Collection.
rh-nodejs10-runtime
rh-nodejs10-nodejs
rh-nodejs10-npm
```

So the main package was build end of Oct 2018. The rh-nodejs10-nodejs was build on Nov. 2018 and is based on the source package rh-nodejs10-nodejs-10.10.0-2.el7.src.rpm.

My Question is: Was there any update since November for this package?

When I searched for CVEs I found something on [NodeJS homepage](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/february-2019-security-releases/) which says NodeJS10 is vulnerable for CVE-2019-5737.
The text says:

"This vulnerability is an extension of CVE-2018-12121, addressed in November, 2018. The 40 second timeout and its adjustment by server.headersTimeout apply to this fix as in CVE-2018-12121."

As non-native speaker I would guess an already patched system against CVE-2018-12121 is unvulnerable?

If so: Is the needed patch applied in the SCL-Version?

```
rpm -q --changelog rh-nodejs10-nodejs | less
* Mi Okt 31 2018 Zuzana Svetlikova <zsvetlik@redhat.com> - 10.10.0-2
- Resolves: RHBZ#1584252
- comment out native.req file to prevent conflict with other Node.js
- installations (rhbz#1637922)

* Fr Sep 14 2018 Zuzana Svetlikova <zsvetlik@redhat.com> - 10.10.0-1
- rebase to v10.10.0
- update patches for openssl
- TODO: remove useless comments, fix failing tests, update bundled provides
```

Last entry is from Oct / 2018. So I guess not patched?

Regards
Markus